# Creating Excel project from Visual Studio with no VSTO file

Tags: excel, visual-studio-2010, vsto

I created an Excel Workbook project using Visual Basic 2010 (.Net 4.0) in Visual Studio, when I start a New Project gives me three options, Excel 2010 Add-In, Excel 2010 Template and Excel 2010 Workbook.

I went for Excel 2010 Workbook, because in the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8553caee(v=vs.100).aspx) I found that:

> However, the Word Template and Excel Template project templates makes it easy for users to create new local document or workbook copies of the customized template in your solution. The features in your solution are available from the new document that the user creates from the template.

So, what I understand is if I created the solution in a workbook, I could send it to my peers and they will be able to use the solution from the workbook itself. The thing is that when they open the workbook they are asked to install a VSTO file:

[VSTO issue image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26a8t.png)

I thought that by using Document-Level Customization project would get me free of the VSTO, but no.

I've read through the whole related MSDN pages with no solution to my issue.

Therefore my questions are:

- Does anybody know how to create the solution without using the VSTO file?
- What would you recommend me to do?

Thank you very much for taking your time to read my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VSTO links code with an Excel workbook or Word document. There is no other possibility using the .NET Framework to directly associate code with an Office file. A VSTO solution must be installed and trusted.

If you want code that resides *in* the workbook you need to use VBA (Visual Basic for Applications). VBA is the "native" Office programming language. This object model is used by VSTO, so your possibilities remain pretty much the same.

Linking code to the file, rather than embedding it in the file, was one of the major selling points for VSTO when it was introduced something over ten years ago. That makes it simpler to *maintain* code that's shared among multiple users. With VBA embedded in a file, if you make a change, you have to distribute the file again to all users. Using VSTO the change can be made in one place and it propagates to all users.

Comment: Awesome, Thanks a lot, Ciny!, that was one of then thing I did not understood from MSDN.